# Clematis identification

Tags: identification, vines

I once owned a Polish clematis which changed name approx 10-12 years ago & since moving to Scarborough would like to obtain again. Unfortunately I only know it by it's old name which I can only spell phonetically - 
                               Maximawenya?

It's a very vigorous, white plant, late flowering. Hope you can help?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you please add pictures so we can see your plant? They're useful in general, but especially with [identification](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) questions. Check [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) for more explanation, Also, we remove names. Put any details about yourself on your profile page. Have a look around our [help] to learn about our system, and let us know if you have any questions! Have fun!

Comment: @Sue "I once owned" and "would like to obtain again" - there's a good chance OP doesn't have photos ;-)

Comment: @Stephie Oops, I missed that! Good point, thanks! Michael, I'm sorry I asked you for pictures of something you don't even have! That sounds like a nice flower, and I hope we can help you find it!

Answer (score 6):

The clematis you describe is probably the sweet autumn clematis which is sold as C. maximowicziana, C. paniculata and C. dioscoreifolia and is also remarkably similar in habit and appearance to the better behaved [Clematis ligusticifolia 'Prairie Traveler's Joy'](http://www.perennials.com/plants/clematis-prairie-travelers-joy.html) and [Clematis mandshurica](http://www.onrockgarden.com/plant_of_the_month/2015-09).

- hardy from zone 2 up
- fragrant autumn bloomer with small cruciform pure white flowers
- climbs at least 20 feet (~6 m)
- medium well drained soil and tolerates shade
- aggressive self seeder which has escaped cultivation in the US Eastern and Midwest

See [here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a300) for details

This image is from Wikipedia labelled Clematis paniculata

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer as such, but there's too much to ask to put in a comment. Phonetic spelling of the name isn't much use I'm afraid. You've said its late flowering and vigorous, so its likely a Prune group 3 or viticella group type, but it would be helpful if you could describe the flowers and foliage. For instance, were the flowers very large, or were there lots of small flowers? What colour were the stamens in the centre? Were the flowers double or single? How vigorous was it in terms of height and spread, around 15 feet or 35 feet high? was it deciduous or evergreen?

There are hundreds of varieties of clematis, so this extra information should help to narrow down the field, so please edit your question adding as much information as possible.